# Computer Adaptive Testing Simulation (Catsim) library for adaptive tests

Tags: python, stat

I am building a model for adaptive testing where I want to feed some responses and according to the response I want to extract the next question from my item bank according to the previous response. For eg. I have answered a question of complexity Medium and I failed in that so the next question thrown to me should be of the same topic but of Low complexity.
I am using catsim for this but I am nowhere close to it.
I have the following questions:

1. I have just difficulty variable and the matrix looks like [a,b,c,d] where b is difficulty variable and I want to know what to feed in matrix in place of a,c and d.
2. What kind of selector and estimator doI have to use to fulfil my purpose.
3. Suggest me ways to take this forward i.e ways to do this using catsim or if there is any other way to do it.

I have been using examples from the following site https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14zEWoDudBCXF0NO-qgzoQpWUGBcJ2lPH?usp=sharing#scrollTo=w16lhjAyIEBl